# plotFit - data plotted as bars instead of points?

Tags: r, bar-chart, scatter-plot, nls

I am using the **plotFit** function in the **investr** package in R to display my data as follows:

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJKjG.png)

The code I am using to generate this is simply:

```
plotFit(nls model, interval = "confidence", level = 0.95, pch = 19, shade = TRUE,
    col.conf = "seagreen2", col.fit = "green", lwd.fit = 2,
    ylim = c(y1,y2), xlim = c(x1,x2), 
    xaxp = c(0,200,10), n = 100,
    ylab = "", xlab = "",
    main = "")
```

Is there a simple way that I could adapt the code to plot the data as bars, rather than points?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `type = "h"`. For example,

```
    fit <- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
    library(investr)
    plotFit(fit)
    plotFit(fit, type = "h", lwd = 3)
```